# Microsoft Graph - any way to "share" my application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have created new Application on page: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList

using AppId and AppKey I can get token and call Microsoft Graph methods. It works fine. But it works only for my admin console, so, if I call method to add new domain it adds new domain to my admin console.
Our business model creates admin console per our client. And we need to setup individual domains for their admin consoles etc.

I need to call Microsoft Graph add domain method to add domain to another admin console! I see a solution is creating one more application per client, under their admin credentials, and then call Microsoft Graph with AppId/AppKey newly created individual Application. But I need to do it automatically and no API to do it (as I understand).

Any way to use one common Application and call Microsoft Graph methods to do actions inside another admin console?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your app registration (in the new preview application registration pages in the Azure AD portal) you need to select the following option:

`Accounts in any organizational directory`

This will allow users in another tenant to consent to using your application. This will mean you can use your app id and secret with other tenants.